# Negative look ahead regex: Match one of several substrings down the line

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to implement a negative lookahead in a regex (in Python) to help me identify cases in which a particular match is not followed by any of a few substrings *anywhere down the line*. I'm implementing this via `Pandas.Series.str.contains()`. As an oversimplified example, suppose I am trying to match the substring `CAT`, unless `DOG` or `PIG` appear anywhere later in the substring:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var':['THE CAT IS MINE','THE CAT AND THE DOG', 'THE CAT AND THE PIG']})
```

The expected results would only return a match for the first element. The following [link](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground) describes such a scenario when your look aheads/behinds might have to generalize beyond the immediate surroundings, but only for simple digits/letters (e.g., using `(?=[^5]*5)`). I couldn't generalize this tip for my use case. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you want here is:

```
\bCAT\b(?!.*\b(?:DOG|PIG)\b)
```

This will match the word `CAT` provided that neither `DOG` or `PIG` occur later in the string.

Python code:

```
df[df["var"].str.contains(fr'\bCAT\b(?!.*\b(?:DOG|PIG)\b)', regex=True)]
```